# Fish dynamically define a function

Tags: fish

```
function fish_title; echo bar; end
```

I'd like to create a `set_title` function that will give the equivalent result of the above i.e. by running `set_title bar`. Any ideas?

Comment: Your question and the code snippet don't look related. Please elaborate. What's your *real* problem?

Comment: @glennjackman Can you explain how your snippet would work? As far as I understand `fish_title` is called every-time a command finishes execution in shell, even if you have a switch to accept $argv in the function, the title will revert the next time you run a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it now. You need this:

```fish
function set_title -a new_title
    eval "function fish_title; echo $new_title; end"
end
```